# onEdit only working for first row when pasting values

Tags: google-apps-script, eventtrigger

I am working on a sheet that tracks the number of times a certain cell value is changed. I am very much a novice, and tweaked some code I found to fit my sheet. It works when I edit one cell at a time, but when I paste values into multiple cells in the column I want to track, only the first row of the edit-counting column updates.

Here is my current code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.columnStart != 10 || e.range.rowStart < 2) return;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var active_range = ss.getActiveRange();

  ss.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 13).setValue(ss.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(),    13).getValue()+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 10 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,12,e.range.rowEnd - e.range.rowStart + 1).setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi  - I just tried this, and it is still only editing the first row in the column when I copy and paste values.

Comment: I tried this updated version to and it's not working at all now.

Comment: It works for me.  You cannot run code like this from the script editor unless you supply the event object

Comment: Hi, sorry for the long delay. I have it working now, but it is still only editing the first row. For clarification: In each cell of column 10, a calendar pop up appears and I can choose the date that I last contacted the sales lead in that row. When I do one at a time, the increment counter in column 13 does increase by 1.  When I contact multiple leads on the same day, I would like to be able to paste the current date into multiple rows and have the increment counter in col 13 increase by 1 in every row. With my code and your code, it is only working in the first row of the pasted range.